# Cannot change Background Color ONLY with CSS

Tags: html, css, hover, background-color, pseudo-class

Good morning,

I'm trying to change the background color on a link when the user hovers over it.  With my current code, the link color will change as expected, but no change to the background color.  If I attach the pseudo-class to a different tag, say "SPAN", then everything works as it should.  I naturally suspect the "A" tag is to blame, but I can't figure it out at all.  Been staring at this thing since last night.  Markup:

```
    <div id="thumbAboutWrap">
        <h4 class="contact">ADAM [AT] LAYEREDFEEDBACK [DOT] COM</h4>
        <a class="contact" href="#"><h4>FACEBOOK</h4></a>
        <a class="contact" href="#"><h4>LAST.FM</h4></a>
        <a class="contact" href="#"><h4>LINKEDIN</h4><a/>
    </div><!--thumbAboutWrap-->
```

CSS:

```
a.contact {
font-size:50px;
font-weight:800;
}

a.contact:hover {
background-color:#000;
color:#FFF;
}
```

I'm also using Meyer's reset if that makes a difference.  So far it's been problem-free.

Comment: Is there a background colour set on the h4 tags?

Comment: @thedaian - there isn't, but that does indeed seems to be the root cause of the problem - see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C7UKp/); compare the first link and the second, where I've added the `h4` to the hover selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is down to the `<h4>` tags you've got inside the `<a>` tags. You're styling the `<a>`, not the `<h4>`.

Two solutions:

Firstly, remove the `<h4>` tags entirely. This will solve the problem, and to be honest, those `<h4>` tags really aren't necessary (you're setting the font size on the `<a>` anyway).

Alternatively, if you want to keep your markup as it is, you'll need to add `h4` to your styles (particularly the hover style), like so:

```
a.contact:hover h4 {
  background-color:#000;
  color:#FFF;
}
```

Hope that helps.

[EDIT]

Demonstration of the difference it makes to add the `h4` to the hover selector can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/C7UKp/

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Works great.  I added the h4 tag so I could get some easy line breaks.  I hate these kinds of problems; I know it's got a simple solution, but after awhile it seems impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your `css`

```
a.contact {
font-size:50px;
font-weight:800;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xk7Jp/1/